# css files are not generated separately with extract-text-webpack-plugin using webpack 3

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-loader

I was trying to create a separate bundle for css based on the chunks name using extract-text-webpack-plugin with webpack@3.6.0.

I have spent more time and googled on identifying on the issue, but i could not find it.
i have tried more options for this.

i will share my webpack.config.js file here,

I have added a web pack config in bitbucket server. please find it from below URL
https://bitbucket.org/nishanth7475/webpackconfigalone/src/dca35d8c0eb31debfcefa2f7f282f987604b6d97?at=master

Comment: Hope you are not setting DONT_EXTRACT_STYLES env variable. And, I hope you are importing your css/scss files in your js - import './styles/style.scss'; ?

Comment: Yes, Correct @Vishal Malik, we are not setting DONT_EXTRACT_STYLES and importing scss/css file in the js file.